# Apple Sign In: Is 'user' credential returned by Apple permanent?

Tags: apple-sign-in

I am able to successfully access the credential returned by Apple as part of it's new (WWDC '19 -- iOS 13) Sign In With Apple library.

The credential is accessed in this delegate method:

```swift
extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
         //here is credentials . 
        }
    }
}
```

One then uses 'user' property to extract the user id:

```swift
    credential.user 
    //returns, for example, '000046.20082df1df9a41b78cd1552979288e19.2346' dummy value
```

**Is this 'user' property understood to be static / permanent for that specific AppleID (and perhaps that specific app)?**

(I am accessing a sync API and would like to hardcode user credentials from that 44 character Apple 'user' credential.)

Comment: Am I crazy, or is is this essential question not answered anywhere in apple's documentation?

Comment: @JonahKatz you are not crazy and I think we'll never get the answers we need. From my testing the user property is changing under the same developer account for the same AppleID.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The user identifier property of `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` is a stable unique identifier between an Apple ID and Developer Team. Application revocations will not affect the stability of the user ID. This also means that among a developer team's set of applications the user ID will be the same, making it optimal for synchronization among a developer's apps.

---

#### Edit for App Transfers:

Transferring an application from one developer team to another will indeed cause the user identifier to change, since it's scoped as a stable user identifier per team.

The best practice when transferring an app that uses Sign in with Apple will be to use an Apple API endpoint to map the user IDs for the old team with user IDs for the new team. If for some reason a developer does not use the API endpoint, *AuthenticationServices* supports application transfers by accepting the old user ID in an `ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest` and the new user ID will be returned.

Generally, *AuthenticationServices* will do the right thing. However, if a user deletes an app associated with Team A (and used Sign in with Apple for said app), then reinstalls the same app now associated with Team B, the only way to associate the two user IDs will be by using the API endpoint.

---

Source: I'm an engineer on the team responsible for Sign in With Apple.

Comment: I still can't figure out where `ASPasswordCredential` comes into play.  Where is it getting the username and password from?

Comment: @Gargoyle Password credential requests retrieve a username and password from keychain entires for an app’s associated domains. It’s offered to help avoid account forking.

Comment: But based on what keys? I can’t find any examples of how to store the data in the first place.

Comment: @Gargoyle You can find more information at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials

Comment: Thanks, @DaveAMoore.  So if I understand right to use the ASPasswordCredential part you'd have to have configured an associated domain for your website, and the user would have had to log into the website and stored credentials via the browser. If they did that, then they'd get a username/password there.

Comment: @Gargoyle Correct, and you can also save the password credential directly from your app, too. So the recommendation is to save a user’s credentials using the shared credential API in your app. But it will also associate with credentials saved by Safari, too.

Comment: Sorry, @DaveAMoore, one more question.  I've saved my credential with the `SecAddSharedWebCredential` API as you suggested.  However, when `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider` is sent as part of the request, how's it know which username to lookup in the associated domain web credential?  I'm not seeing how to connect the dots there.

Comment: @Gargoyle we show a list of all the credentials saved for your application’s associated domains. From there the user can select which username they want to use and after a quick biometric auth, your application is given a password credential.

Comment: I found that thanks @DaveAMoore   Unfortunately that list does not scroll and so I can’t get to the actual credential for this app.

Comment: @DaveAMoore question on the uniqueness... let's say your app has to move to another developer account. Now let's say the user had an account, deleted the app and re install it right after when the transfer occurred. How will that come into play? Will the user still have the same identifier? If not, how are you supposed to match this user with the one in the back-end? Thank you!

Comment: @BenjaminClanet Updated my answer with information regarding application transfers, hope that helps!

Comment: ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential.h has a comment for `user` saying, "The identifier will remain stable as long as the user is connected with the requesting client.  The value may change upon user disconnecting from the identity provider." Having to say connected doesn't sound very stable.